# mysql select records with lowest value

Tags: mysql, division

I have a table with

total_price
units
unitname

I want to select the records where total_price/units is the lowest.

How do I perform division in a query AND then select the record with the lowest value?

(I would also like to group by unitname - i.e. in case one is ounces and one is liters)

Answer (score 1):

You just use division in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from t
order by total_price / units
limit 1;
```

Just to be safe -- in the event that `units` is 0 -- you could do:

```
select *
from t
where units <> 0
order by total_price / units
limit 1;
```

If you want this by `unit_name` then you want to use `min()`:

```
select unit_name, min(total_price / units)
from t
group by unit_name
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly.  One comment:  I am storing total_price and units as "varchar" and yet the arithmetic still works (I can even use the ROUND ($var,x) function to echo out a number with x decimal places.  Is there any reason I should want to change the fields to int or some other number field if storing the number in varchar seems to work?

Comment: @user2557039 . . . You want to store values in their native format for a lot of reasons.  Arithmetic is faster.  Conversion errors or misunderstanding are not an issue.  Joins on the fields behave as expected.

Comment: @user2557039 Please select this as your Accepted Answer if it has answered your question.